# How can I user LINQ to get a IList<string> from a multi-table join?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server 2012 database and I am using Entity Framework 6.1 to access data.

I have the following entities that are joined to each other with Primary Key and Foreign Key relationships. What I would like to do is to get a simple collection of values of the Quid parameter in the Questions table where the taskId matches a value that is chosen outside of this code.

> Task contains Objective contains ObjectiveDetail contains SubTopic contains Problems contations
>   Questions

I created the following LINQ statement. It seems not to work and I need some advice on what I am doing wrong and how the statement could be made to get what I need. In particular I am not sure about the way I do the join with all the many .Selects and also the select to give me the output.

```
var quids = db.Tasks
        .Include(e => e.Objectives
            .Select(o => o.ObjectiveDetails
                .Select(od => od.SubTopics
                    .Select(s => s.Problems
                        .Select(p => p.Questions)))))
        .Where(t => t.TaskId == taskId)
        .Select(e => e.Objectives
            .Select(o => o.ObjectiveDetails
                .Select(od => od.SubTopics
                    .Select(s => s.Problems
                        .Select(p => p.Questions
                            .Select(q => q.QuestionUId))))))
                            .ToList();
```

However this gives me a very confusing output and certainly not the simple IList of Quids 
that I would like. Here are my classes for reference. I removed additional fields and hopefully just left the important ones.

```
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.Objectives = new HashSet<Objective>();
    }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }

}

public class Objective
{
    public Objective()
    {
        this.ObjectiveDetails = new HashSet<ObjectiveDetail>();
    }

    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public ObjectiveDetail()
    {
        this.SubTopics = new HashSet<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public virtual Objective Objective { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public class SubTopic
{
    public SubTopic()
    {
        this.Problems = new HashSet<Problem>();
    }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Problem> Problems { get; set; }
}

public class Problem
{
    public Problem()
    {
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubTopic SubTopic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; } 
    public string QuestionUId { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }

}
```

Please note the many-many relationship between SubTopic and ObjectiveDetail. This I think makes it more difficult.

Comment: Deleted my previous answer as the many-to-many relationship changes things. Do you know why a navigation link is missing? Problem should have a SubTopic property. If you just have an id it makes it harder to form a query.

Comment: @Andy - My apologies. I was concerned I would miss something when trying to edit the question. You are correct. Problem does have a SubTopic property and I added this back into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your outer `Select` calls produces a sequence for each item. This gives you nested sequences and probably a confusing `ToString` debug output.

What you probably meant was to use `SelectMany` to flatten the nested sequences.

The `Include` in your query cannot possibly help because you are just returning a list of strings. There is nothing to include in a string. Better remove it. Who knows what code EF generates from it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your need, you can simply start from the `Question` DbSet instead of the task:

```
var uids = db.Questions.Where(q => q.Problem.SubTopic
                                    .ObjectiveDetails
                                    .Any(od => od.Objective.TaskId == taskId))
                       .Select(q => q.QuestionUId)
                       .ToList();
```

This will take all `Question` which has at least one objective with the `TaskId` equal to `taskId` then project the `QuestionUid` and put it in a list.